# How to select multi column with group by one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have..

```
Date         ID   Qty  
2019/5/1     A    11  
2019/6/1     A    22 
2019/7/1     B    33  
2019/6/1     B    44
```

I need data of ID and Qty at Max(Date) of each ID as below

```
Date         ID   Qty  
2019/6/1     A    22
2019/7/1     B    33
```

I use..

```
select max(Date),ID,Qty from table group by ID,Qty
```

but the result is not what I expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table_name t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date, ID 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY ID
) tMAX ON t.ID = tMAX.ID AND t.Date = tMAX.Date
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5a010c832709186e2470ec90c2a1c2a)

Answer (score 2):

`group by` probably isn't the right tool for the job. Instead, you could use `rank` to find the top row per group, and filter according to it:

```
SELECT date, id, qty
FROM   (SELECT date, id, qty, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: thank you very much. that is work but i don't understand the code

Comment: this is explained in a blog over here: http://coding.feron.it/2012/08/mssql-having-maxid-id-problem-row_number-partition/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Date,
       ID,
       Qty 
FROM
(
SELECT Date,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Grp,
       ID,
       Qty 
FROM <Table>
)Dt
WHERE Dt.Grp = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use correlated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where date=( select max(date) from table_name t2 where t2.id=t1.id)
```